# VB.NET Multi file open issue

Tags: vb.net, file

I am new to vb.net and I want to make a simple program that contains a multi file option.
I found this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_pK0blSQr4
When I run this, the iterator makes an extra iteration wich causes an error.
I tried to decrement the for loop count by one but that didn't work, the for loop went to original value.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 Private Sub load_acc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles load_acc.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text file|*.txt|All files| *.*"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        For x = 0 To (OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Count - 1)
            acc_list.Items.Add(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(x))
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean by extra iteration?  What you describe sounds impossible - the FileNames property is going to have what the user selected, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
For x = 0 To (OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Count - 1)
```

(note the "s" on FileNames) instead of

```
For x = 0 To (OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Count - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use for each instead

```
   For each file as string in OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
       acc_list.Items.Add(file) 
   Next
```